# Bone position affects mesh but its scale does not

Tags: armature, bones

I've purchased a human basemesh which I intend to use to create various characters and I'm trying to learn how it works first. The mesh has one particular bone that when moved it affects the mesh but when scaled it does not. All the other bones affect the mesh when scaled this is the only one that does not. I've tried to compare the properties of this bone with the others, the properties that can be found in the right side panels (ex: Context Bone, Object Data, Object etc...) while in Armature Pose Mode and Edit Mode and I can't seem to find what makes this bone's scale not affect the mesh. Any idea what could be causing this and where else I should look? I'm using Blender 2.8 which I'm not very used to yet so that could be a factor as well.

Thank you!

P.S.: I should have mentioned it's the jaw bone.

Comment: May be this bone just controls an other bone and that deformes the mesh.

Comment: I should have mentioned it's the jaw bone.

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: It's a purchased file so unfortunately I can't. I did find a solution which for my purposes works fine. I created a new bone, copied the vertex group to it so it has the same weight on the mesh and then just deleted the old bone. So I basically have the same bone as before but it now also works with scale :)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like it's the base/root bone for the position of your model in 3D space. Usually you just leave the bone as it is and the bone which comes after that will be the first bone with the purpose of actually manipulating the mesh. I suspect that on this second bone in the *Relations* the checkbox for *Inherit Scale* is ticked off.
[image]

Comment: I should have mentioned it's the jaw bone.

Comment: In that case it could be a simple helper bone. Is there anything rigged to it? And is it parent to another bone? If it's the parent to another bone check for *Inherit Scale* on that bone.

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly! I'm not sure what "Is there anything rigged to it" means. If I move the bone, the jaw moves so it affects a certain set of vertices. It is parented to the head bone and it does indeed have "inherit scale". Many of the other bones in the rig have "inherit scale" as well. The other bones who also have inherit scale and a parent still affect the mesh when they're scaled unlike this one. With or without "inherit scale" checked and with or without a parent, this jaw bone does not affect any vertices when scaled, only when moved.

Comment: *rigged* means that you have vertices bound to this bone. In a usual setup a parent bone also affects the child bones (any bone connected directly to it). So for example you move the hand bone all the finger bones move with it. In your case there is probably a child bone connected to the one you want to scale. On this child bone the *Inherit Scale* might be ticked off. Also the mesh of the jaw is probably bound to that child bone.

Comment: In both pose mode and armature edit mode I went and did alt+H to make sure there are no hidden bones. Then, in both pose and armature edit mode I tried both with inherit scale disabled on everything and enabled on everything and the jaw bone still didn't change the jaw vertices when scaled :( I'm going to try and contact the author of the rig and see if he's able to help.

Comment: Btw, I also tried deleting everything but the mesh and that one bone to see if anything else in the scene was affecting it and the result was the same.

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell without actually seeing the blend file, but as it is a purchase you can't share it. You could go into *Weight Paint* and take a look there for anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: I found a solution which isn't technically a solution but it does the job in my case. I created a new bone, copied the vertex group to it so it has the same weight on the mesh and then just deleted the old bone. So I basically have the same bone as before but it now also works with scale :)